# Nginx/uwsgi request buffer or queue

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Our web servers run a Python app behind nginx + uwsgi.

Sometimes we have short spikes (2-5x avg no requests) for a second resulting in some requests getting a 502 if there are no workers available to handle them.

Is there a way for nginx or uwsgi to queue these requests up and serve them when workers become available?

It's better with a short increase in response time rather than getting an error ;-)